# Amazon MWS Feed API - How prquently we can submit "_POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_" Feed?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, web-services, amazon-mws

Here I have problem with multiple feeds. 
I am submitting orders feeds also frequently and Listings feeds also frequently.

Along with that I want to submit Inventory feed also. But it has threshold limit of  30 request every hour. how to handle this.
How does restore rate works.

I am planning to run inventory feed every 2 minute.

thanks in advance

Comment: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_Throttling.html